# cannot select a row in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

**EDIT1 :** used double quotes and single quotes but I am getting same error.

**EDIT2 :** same query is returning me result in mysql shell

I am selecting a row from a table.

```
if(!isset($_GET['title']) || !isset($_GET['user'])){
  echo "hi"; //something come here 
}
else{
 $title = $_GET['title'];
 $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$title);

 $user = $_GET['user'];
 $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$user);
 echo $title ;
 echo $user ;

 // tried giving value directly to test but no luck
 $query = "SELECT * FROM site WHERE client=\"Chaitanya\" && title=\"werdfghb\" "; 
 $result5 = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result5);
 echo $count ;

 while($result9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)){ 
 $kk=$result9['url'];
 echo $kk ;
 }
 $page = $kk; 
 include ( 'counter.php');
 addinfo($page);
}
```

In my database there is a row with columns title and client and the values I entered are in that row but when I `echo count(no of rows)` it is showing `zero`.

Is there anything wrong with code ?

Comment: What is the output if you run the query in MySQL?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: kk in C:\wamp\www\livestream\live.php on line 32

Comment: Try running the query directly in MySQL.

Comment: You need to define $kk outside of the while loop as an empty variable.

Comment: it is showing me the result :)

Comment: What is your error, kk undefined or no rows being returned. Im confused.

Comment: even if there is value in database row it is not returning value (showing  num of rows as 0 ) if the value is returned then kk will get defined

Comment: Ok, you are right about `$kk`, contrary to popular belief `$kk` doesn't need to be define outside the loop if you have a result. But if you have no result the while doesn't get entered so $kk is not set. So before your while loop put an if to check that you have a result.

Comment: thanks  i will check it  but why am i not getting any result , any idea ?

Comment: Because your query doesn't match any rows, its not really more complex than that.

Comment: umm yes but the same query is returning me result in mysql (shell )

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the line

`$page = $kk;`

in this code `$kk` is not declared previously. The defined `$kk` is in the while loop scope.

declare the variable like this in the outer scope from the while loop

```
...
$kk = null;
while($result9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) { 
    $kk = $result9['url'];
    echo $kk ;
}
$page = $kk; 
...
```

**Error on Fetching Data**

You have to crack you SQl into smaller pieces and test the code like this.

1. run the query `SELECT * FROM site` without any `where` and get the count
2. run the query `SELECT * FROM site WHERE client='Chaitanya'` and get the count
3. `SELECT * FROM site WHERE title='werdfghb'` and check the count
4. Then run the whole query

And see the results. This way u can find out in where the issue is in your SQL code. *I prefer you use the mysql client to execute this queries*

Comment: Initialization of `$kk` will still not solve why `$count` has value 0.

Comment: i dont think while loop is the culprit because before the while loop i used mysqli_num_rows and it is retuning me zero , if it returned 1 then kk would get defined

Comment: @NagaInquisitive You need to crack the SQL into smaller pieces and check where the issue is. Also make sure you run the SQL in the mysql client directly and see if this issue still persist.

Comment: i am getting result when i run it in mysql client or shell

Comment: @NagaInquisitive Can you try the SQL without WHERE clause in PHP code and see how it works.

Comment: tried running without WHERE and its showing me count is 12 , but there are like 50-60 rows in site database

Comment: if i try running it with client and or user it is returning 0 rows

Comment: So obviously there is a deeper issue. Are you SURE your connected to the right DB?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment, `$kk` is undefined in the `$page = $kk;`, since it is declared in the `while` loop.

Do something like:

```
$kk = '';   //can also do $kk=NULL; if you want.
while($result9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) { 
    $kk=$result9['url'];
    echo $kk ;
}
$page = $kk;
```

Comment: got rid of error but my problem is that if there is a row with the values i have given , i am not getting any result , i am getting 0 if use mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 0):

try this one

$client = "Chaitanya";

$title = "werdfghb";

$query="SELECT * FROM site WHERE client='".$client."' and title='".$title."' ";

you can also use this

$query="SELECT * FROM site WHERE client={$client} and title={$title} ";